# Android Emulator Error "Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

When I try running, I get a bunch of nonsense in the Event Log.

> Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so Emulator:
>   libGL error: driver pointer missing Emulator: libGL error: failed to
>   load driver: nouveau Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver:
>   swrast_dri.so Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>   Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out
>   of range for operation) Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  155
>   (GLX) Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24
>   (X_GLXCreateNewContext) Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0
>   Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  33 Emulator: Current
>   serial number in output stream:  34 Emulator: Process finished with
>   exit code 1 Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver:
>   nouveau_dri.so Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing Emulator:
>   libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau Emulator: libGL error:
>   unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so Emulator: libGL error: failed to
>   load driver: swrast Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue
>   (integer parameter out of range for operation) Emulator: Major opcode
>   of failed request:  155 (GLX) Emulator: Minor opcode of failed
>   request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext) Emulator: Value in failed
>   request:  0x0 Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  33 Emulator:
>   Current serial number in output stream:  34 Emulator: Process finished
>   with exit code 1 Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver:
>   nouveau_dri.so Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing Emulator:
>   libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau Emulator: libGL error:
>   unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so Emulator: libGL error: failed to
>   load driver: swrast Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue
>   (integer parameter out of range for operation) Emulator: Major opcode
>   of failed request:  155 (GLX) Emulator: Minor opcode of failed
>   request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext) Emulator: Value in failed
>   request:  0x0 Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  33 Emulator:
>   Current serial number in output stream:  34 Emulator: Process finished
>   with exit code 1 Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver:
>   nouveau_dri.so Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing Emulator:
>   libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau Emulator: libGL error:
>   unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so Emulator: libGL error: failed to
>   load driver: swrast Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue
>   (integer parameter out of range for operation) Emulator: Major opcode
>   of failed request:  155 (GLX) Emulator: Minor opcode of failed
>   request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext) Emulator: Value in failed
>   request:  0x0 Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  33 Emulator:
>   Current serial number in output stream:  34 Emulator: Process finished
>   with exit code 1

Please help!

Comment: Please format your question and add some more details about your problem.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, go to Microsoft download center and install DriverX for Runtime web Installer, then check your Emulator.